# How to reduce numbers in python after comma without rounding

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to reduce numbers in python after comma without rounding
Example : I have x = 2.97656
I want it to be 2.9 not 3.0
Thank you

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what didn't work. Hint: convert to a string. Also note that that is not a comma but a "period" or "full-stop" depending on where you're based.

Comment: Do it with string manipulation. Convert the number into string, look for the dot, split and convert it back into number.

Comment: x= 2.978
>>> print(round(x,1))
3.0

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `math.round()` you can use `math.floor()`:

```
import math
x = 2.97656
print(math.floor(x * 10) / 10)
#Output = 2.9
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use round(var , number precision )
see this link please to more info
**https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/precision-handling-python/**